# Pivot table from MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

I'm newbie in MySQL i want create pivot table by mysql table like this:

My table:

```
*------------*-------*----------------*-------*------------*
|    Name    | Place |  Kind of work  | Hours |    Date    |
*------------*-------*----------------*-------*------------*
| Test Test  |  abc  |      abc       |   5   | 2020-01-20 |
| Test1 Test1|  abc  |      abc       |   6   | 2020-01-21 |
| Test2 Test2|  abc  |      abc       |   7   | 2020-01-21 |
| Test Test  |  abc  |      abc       |   5   | 2020-01-23 |
| Test1 Test1|  abc  |      abc       |   6   | 2020-01-24 |
| Test2 Test2|  abc  |      abc       |   7   | 2020-01-25 |
*------------*-------*----------------*-------*------------*
```

I want to get this by mysql select (if it is possible)

```
*---------------------*------------*------------*------------*------------*------------*
| Name (group by name)| 2020-01-20 | 2020-01-21 | 2020-01-23 | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-25 |
*---------------------*------------*------------*------------*------------*------------*
| Test Test           |     5      |            |      5     |            |            |
| Test1 Test1         |            |      6     |            |     6      |            |
| Test2 Test2         |            |      7     |            |            |      7     |
*---------------------*------------*------------*------------*------------*------------*
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Dates list is not static? Use stored procedure.

Comment: Mysql pivot table questions are common in this forum try searching myql pivot or mysql conditional aggregation.

Comment: check this link https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/10441/creating-a-pivot-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty nice question as there is no pivot functions in MySQL. Moreover, you seem to need a dynamic number of columns which makes it a bit more difficult than a fixed and pre-determined number of columns.

The only way i know to achieve such a pivot in MySQL is to use a prepared statement as below :

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
          CONCAT(
               'MAX(IF(date = ''',
               date,
               ''', hours, NULL)) AS "',
               date,'"'
          )
     ) INTO @sql
FROM test;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' FROM test GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[**SEE FULL DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=14a20208bb6d3c658d5a97c67eb44f6e)

Comment: Superb! but one problem... is way to add this in wordpress post?

Comment: Ew, sorry I don't know anything about wordpress :/

Comment: Ok, one more question it is possible to set date range in this query? From 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31?

Comment: When i try to run this in phpmyadmin on server i get error: 
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'FROM test GROUP BY name' in line 1. When i try this in phpmyadmin on local computer its working. Can somene help me?

Comment: For the date range i think you could add a where clause at the end of the 'group_concat' query like this => INTO @sql FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31';

Comment: About phpmyadmin i do not have any idea :/ does test table exist ? try to replace ' with " => CONCAT("SELECT name, ", @sql, " FROM test GROUP BY name");

Comment: I change that but no effect. Mayby there must be only " ? How do that?

Comment: I don't konw where is problem. Another question how create view from this statement?

Comment: Problem was in server. At the start i must use SET SESSION group_concat_max_len =10000; then stmt works. But how get mysql view from this statement?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution this is code for my native table:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
'MAX(IF(datapracy = "', datapracy, '" , liczbagodzin, NULL)) AS "', datapracy, '"'
)
) INTO @sql
FROM wp_wpdatatable_1_1 WHERE datapracy BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31';

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT imieinazwiskopracownika, ", @sql, " FROM wp_wpdatatable_1_1 GROUP BY imieinazwiskopracownika");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But now i have question how create from this stmt mysql view?

Answer (score 1):

So... it's not possible to execute this stmt on big table:

`SET SESSION group_concat_max_len =20000;
SET @sql = NULL; 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(datapracy = "', datapracy, '" , liczbagodzin, NULL)) AS "', datapracy, '"' ) ) INTO @sql FROM STYCZEN2020PF1; 
SET @sql = CONCAT("create view STYCZEN2020PF2 as SELECT nowakolumna, ", @sql, " FROM STYCZEN2020PF1 GROUP BY nowakolumna"); 
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

We need creat view of month first:

`Create or replace view STYCZEN2020PF1 AS
Select t2.`nowakolumna`, t1.datapracy, sum(t1.liczbagodzin) as liczbagodzin from wp_wpdatatable_5 as t2, wp_wpdatatable_1_1 as`t1`where t2.`wdt_ID`= t1.`imieinazwiskopracownika`AND t1.datapracy BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31' group by t1.datapracy, t2.nowakolumna HAVING COUNT(*)`

And after create second pivot view from first stmt. This is solution.
In the end we should select * from view.

Big thanks for help.